# How broadly is the term “Sanfte Mobilität” used?

Tags: usage

As part of tourism packages I have come across the term "*Sanfte Mobilität*" and it seems to indicate packages where people take public transport to and from their destination as well as use non-emission vehicles for local day trips.

Has this been coined specifically for Alpen tourism or could I use this term in a more general sense?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think "**Sanfte Mobilität**" is a term that is mainly used for marketing purposes or in political agendas. It is not widely used in colloquial language.

It depends on the context where you want to use it, if the term is appropriate or not. But it is not specific for a touristic region and can be used in a more general sense.

I, personally, prefer to say something like "umweltfreundliche Verkehrsmittel benutzen" (to use environmentally friendly means of transport), but this is not an exact replacement.

See https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sanfte_Mobilit%C3%A4t or https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sustainable_transport